# Transpose every other row in a google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I've been given a badly formatted sheet where there are thousands of records with X and corresponding Y value in the following row rather than the same row and next column.

[image]

Is there a function that will allow me to copy altering rows?

So...

```
A2 goes into B2 and A3 goes into C2
A4 goes into B3 and A5 goes into C3
```

etc

[image]

A sample sheet is in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fB2rpVdJiTmp96sjGZiIYvKxEL9DLiK7W7QU8-4AN3A/edit?usp=sharing

I'd prefer a Google Sheet solution but excel is fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete everything in B2:C range and try:

```
={FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"", MOD(ROW(A2:A), 2)=0),
  FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"", MOD(ROW(A2:A)+1, 2)=0)}
```

[image: 0]