# How to use importxml function just once instead of using it twice for 2 different columns in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to fetch latest articles on covid from a website. I am able to retrieve the required data as follows:

The below formula fetches Title and News Source
`=IMPORTXML("https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/World+News/Asia/India/Coronavirus?type=ln","//div[@data-more]//div[@class='hl '][position()<=10]/*")`

and the below formula fetches the news url

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/World+News/Asia/India/Coronavirus?type=ln","//div[@data-more]//div[@class='hl '][position()<=10]/div[@class='hl__inner']/a[@class='hll']/@href")`

Now the problem is that sometimes the feed gets updated so frequently that both the formulas fetch data not at the same level. So I get news url of some other in ROW1 and its title and source are in ROW2. Please correct me if I am wrong to think that this is happening because I am using 2 separate formulas instead of 1.

I would like to use one single importxml to fetch 3 columns (title, source and source url), if possible. Please also suggest me if there is some other better way to do so. Here is a screenshot of the results.

[Screenshot of importxml data result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbCAT.png)

Thank you in advance :)

Here is another screenshot with urls mentioned below in order:
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N69g3.png)

https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594291?-14432:11
https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594284?-14432:11
https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594264?-14432:11
https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594225?-14432:11
https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594213?-14432:11
https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594206?-14432:11
https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594153?-14432:11
https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594123?-14432:11
https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594097?-14432:11
https: //c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1079594087?-14432:11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SUGGESTION:**

You can concatenate multiple `xpath_query` in a single **IMPORTXML** formula using `|` sign. Something like this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/World+News/Asia/India/Coronavirus?type=ln", 
 "//div[@data-more]//div[@class='hl '][position()<=10]/* | 
  //div[@data-more]//div[@class='hl '][position()<=10]/div[@class='hl__inner']/a[@class='hll']/@href")
```

However, this method will give you this result, where all `xpath_query` data are placed into one column:

[image]

**LIMITATIONS**

I tried looking further for a way to place the links to the next column beside their titles (tried advanced `TRANSPOSE` function with `IMPORTXML` implementation) but it looks it is quite tricky to achieve.

This may not be ideal for your goal, but I have found this solution on [Transpose every other row in a google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132213) and this is as far as I can get:

[image]

Comment: I have used your method and made some changes to the filter formula and the importxml xpath and got the desired result. Thank you so much. Now all the columns seem to be in sync. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`={IMPORTXML("https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/World+News/Asia/India/Coronavirus?type=ln","//div[@data-more]//div[@class='hl '][position()<=10]/*"),IMPORTXML("https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/World+News/Asia/India/Coronavirus?type=ln","//div[@data-more]//div[@class='hl '][position()<=10]/div[@class='hl__inner']/a[@class='hll']/@href")}`

The two separate `IMPORTXML` are within `{}`, separated by a `,`.

[image]

Sample news:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Still getting the same issue. The title and source in row 1 has url in row 2 and so on. Can we retrieve the 3 columns by using just 1 importxml function?

Comment: No sure what the issue is, sorry. It aligns for me. I'll add screengrabs (above).

Comment: It is giving correct results when the frequency of incoming new news feed is less. When the feeds keep coming every minute or so, the 2 formulae sometimes give different values. Adding the screenshot above and here are the urls of the sample

Comment: Not sure, sorry. Hopefully someone else can pick this up.

Comment: No problem. Thank you.